# How do I target JS to the element a ruby partial was rendered within?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

**I am using AJAX to render javascript partials using Ruby on Rails 5.3. How can I reference the element within in which it has been rendered using javascript/jquery, once the render is complete?**

I have various form partials that are rendered in a single element stored in the footer. Previously I have referenced some javascript in the bottom of my form partials which initialises the modal.

I now want to have two different types of modals, with the possibility of having both open at once. With the creation of the second modal wrapper I now need to work out how I can initialise the correct modal (I may open a modal within a modal, and so must avoid re-initialising an already open modal).

Any help would be great! Thanks all.

---

**I render the partials with the following code:** these occur separately as different requests.

```
$('#modal_partial_normal').html('<%= escape_javascript(render('form1')) %>');

$('#modal_partial_footer').html('<%= escape_javascript(render('form2')) %>');
```

**The JS that initialises the modals** follows the documentation from Materialize [here](https://materializecss.com/modals.html).

```
$("#modal_partial_footer").modal("open");
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="form_modal_wrap">

  <div id="modal_partial_footer" class="modal bottom-sheet modal-fixed-footer">
    ... partial rendered here ...
  </div>

  <div id="modal_partial_normal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    ... partial rendered here ...
  </div>

</div>
```

The JS is working for a single type of modal, but I currently render every modal as a 'footer' modal type so I just trigger it after any rendering of a modal partial. I would like to be able to render some as footers, and others as normal modals. I need to open the normal modal, from the footer modal.

---

## Attempts at a solution

I am trying to work out when a modal has been rendered and initialise the correct type - i.e. the footer or normal type.

**Checking for the successful completion of the AJAX request** triggers just once, when I would like it to, but I cannot tell which element it has been rendered within.

```
$('a[data-remote="true"]').on("ajax:success", function(evt, xhr, settings){
        console.log("AJAX request successful");
});
```

**Recognising changes to the DOM tree** doesn't work as it fires too often and the initialisation fails, although it does let me tell which element has had the partial rendered within it.

```
 $("footer").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "*[id^='modal_partial']", function() { ... });
```

Comment: Several questions: Do you render the forms with same request or you use different requests for each one? Would you be able to provide what is the js that initializes the modals? Lastly - Since you use ids: `#modal_partial_normal` and `#modal_partial_footer` I'm assuming that you might have at most two modals open at the same time - one in `#modal_partial_normal` and one in `#modal_partial_footer`.

Comment: I render the forms with different requests, at different times. I want to be able to open the normal modal from the footer modal. The JS that initialises the modals follows the documentation here https://materializecss.com/modals.html. I've updated the question to have this info

Comment: In case you do it with different requests - have you tried to call `$("#modal_partial_footer").modal("open");` immediately after `$('#modal_partial_footer').html('<%= escape_javascript(render('form2')) %>');` and `$("#modal_partial_normal").modal("open");` after `$('#modal_partial_normal').html('<%= escape_javascript(render('form1')) %>');` in the .js.erb file itself?